# Riemanns surfaces on the reciprocal function

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces

Given a complex function $f(z)=\displaystyle \int\frac{dz}{\sqrt{P(z)}}$, where $P(z)$ is a polynomial of $n$ degree, is it possible to affirm that this function always have Riemann surfaces separated by $2\pi i$?

So, it would be valid to express it as  $f(z) + 2\pi i=\displaystyle \int\frac{dz}{\sqrt {P(z)}}$?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The numerical values are difficult to determine.  In one of the simplest cases, in which $P(z)$ is a quadratic polynomial, the integral is called an.[Elliptic integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral) The numerical values of the periods  of that integral depend on the coefficients of the quadratic in a fashion that has been studied for centuries, notably by Gauss. See also the Schwarz-Christoffel mapping as an application. [Schwarz-Christoffel mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz%E2%80%93Christoffel_mapping)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I am understanding in a correct way, you mean that the function is always periodic, but the value of the period is hard to obtain. Is that true?